# ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver

Tags: wine

I am trying to use Wine, but I get:

```
0054:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\nsiproxy": c0000003
```

I am using version:

```
wine --version
wine-6.0 (Ubuntu 6.0+repack-1ubuntu1)
```

The wine stuff installed on this PC:

```
$ wine --version
wine-6.0 (Ubuntu 6.0+repack-1ubuntu1)
xander@xanderpc:~/MagicaVoxel-0.99.7.0-win64$ dpkg --list | grep wine
ii  dxvk-wine32-development:i386               1.9.4+ds1-1ubuntu1                       i386         Vulkan-based translation layer for Direct3D 9/10/11 - wine32 build
ii  dxvk-wine64-development                    1.9.4+ds1-1ubuntu1                       amd64        Vulkan-based translation layer for Direct3D 9/10/11 - wine64 build
ii  fonts-wine                                 6.0.3~repack-1                           all          Windows API implementation - fonts
ii  libwine-development:amd64                  6.0+repack-1ubuntu1                      amd64        Windows API implementation - library
ii  libwine-development:i386                   6.0+repack-1ubuntu1                      i386         Windows API implementation - library
ii  wine-development                           6.0+repack-1ubuntu1                      all          Windows API implementation - standard suite
ii  wine32-development:i386                    6.0+repack-1ubuntu1                      i386         Windows API implementation - 32-bit binary loader
ii  wine32-development-preloader:i386          6.0+repack-1ubuntu1                      i386         Windows API implementation - prelinked 32-bit binary loader
ii  wine64-development                         6.0+repack-1ubuntu1                      amd64        Windows API implementation - 64-bit binary loader
```

I have no winetricks, and apt-cache search for winetricks comes up zero.

### UPDATE 1

Ok, I added universe repo, and upgraded to Wine 7.3 which is not much better:

```
$ wine MagicaVoxel.exe 
wine: Unhandled page fault on execute access to 00007FBE80E42210 at address 00007FBE80E42210 (thread 0068), starting debugger...
```

...After which it hangs.

**OS:** Ubuntu 22.10

**CPU:** i5-11600K

**GPU:** GeForce RTX 3060 Ti Lite Hash Rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wiped everything wine-related from my system, and went with the WineHQ repositories instead.

Not only does wine work now, it is also a newer version than what is in Ubuntu repositories.

To add the WineHQ repository, use [this guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).